# RDLC Pie Chart doesn't display useful error message when all data points are 0%

Tags: rdlc

Is there a way to set the RDLC pie chart to display a useful error message when all data points are 0%.

At present I am getting this error message in the RDLC viewer, which I can't handle via code because it is not raised as an error.

```
An error occurred during local report processing.
An error occurred during rendering of the report.
An error occurred during rendering of the report.
An error has occurred during rendering of chart chart1. Details: Parameter is not valid.
Parameter is not valid.
```